# Seagate ST1000DM003 and USB-SATA bridge

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I can't get that disk to work with my external case (bridge). Disk is spinning and recognized by Windows, but it doesn't recognize data on it, it can see only one big RAW partition when there are 2. I can't read SMART data either, nor boot from it, so it's not OS related. All my SATA 2 and IDE disks work just fine. Is it because this Seagate is SATA 3? SATA is backward compatible so that doesn't make sense. The bridge can work with disks up to 2TB in capacity, so that's not the problem. Could it be because of used technologies, like APM or something?

Comment: How does it work directly in computer? If ok, then how does it work with data connected via your external case, but power connected to 100% reliable source (eg stationary computer PSU)?

Comment: We need information on the bridge if you want help

Comment: It works perfectly fine when connected to motherboard. Nothing changes when I supply the power from PSU. These are the code names from PCB: ET-3522JM20337 REV: A090905. Producer advertise it as ET-H3522.